# In App Purchase

Tags: android, in-app-billing

How to avoid the purchasing of items which I already bought through INApp billing from android market.. That is the purchase should be avoided second time

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 types for items:
Managed and unmanaged.
If you choose Managed you can't charge twice for the same item.

Read here for more info:
http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_admin.html

Comment: okay.. It avoids the purchasing of the item for the second time for a particular user.. But if another user tries to purchase the same item will it allow to purchase the item ??